# Test All Process and Routes of Apache Camel Junit

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel

I am trying to validate all the processes of route but start is working fine after that it started to break.Please give me some useful reference or sample for this.Thanks in advance.

**test.txt:**

```
F1:L1
F2:L2
F3:L3
```

**Customer.java**

```
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    // getters and setters
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return firstName +":::" + lastName;
    }
}
```

**JUnit and Route:**

```
    public class FileTest7 extends CamelTestSupport {

        @EndpointInject(uri = "direct:teststart")
        private Endpoint start;

        @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:direct:process1")
        private MockEndpoint mockProcess1;

        @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:direct:process2")
        private MockEndpoint mockProcess2;

        @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:direct:process3")
        private MockEndpoint mockProcess3;

        @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:direct:write2File")
        private MockEndpoint mockWrite2File;

        @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:end")
        private MockEndpoint mockEnd;

        @Override
        public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
            return new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    from("file:/var/file.log&noop=true").routeId("MY_ROUTE").to("direct:process1");

                    from("direct:process1").routeId("process1").process(exchange -> {
                        File file = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
                        List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();

                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            String[] names = line.split(",");
                            customers.add(new Customer(names[0], names[1]));
                        }
                        br.close();
                        exchange.getOut().setBody(customers);
                    }).to("direct:process2");

                    from("direct:process2").routeId("process2").split(simple("${body}")).to("direct:process3");

                    from("direct:process3").routeId("process3").process(exchange -> {
                        Customer customer = exchange.getIn().getBody(Customer.class);
                        String content = "Content:" + customer.toString();
                        exchange.getIn().setBody(content);
                    }).to("direct:write2File");

                    //Below updated
from("direct:write2File").routeId("write2File").to("file:/src/test/resources?fileName=test_out.log&fileExist=Append");

                }
            };
        }

        @Override
        protected void doPostSetup() throws Exception {
            context.getRouteDefinition("MY_ROUTE").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    replaceFromWith("direct:teststart");
                    weaveAddLast().to("mock:end");
                }
            });
            context.start();//updated
        }

        @Test
        public void testUnmarshal() throws Exception {

            template.sendBody("direct:teststart", new File("src/test/resources/test.txt"));


            List<Customer> customers = mockProcess1.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody(List.class);
            System.out.println("customers:"+customers.size());

            Customer customer1 = mockProcess2.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody(Customer.class);
            System.out.println("customer1:"+customers.toString());


            String customer = mockProcess3.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody(String.class);
            System.out.println("customer:"+customer);

            String customerString = mockWrite2File.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody(String.class);
            System.out.println("Customer String:"+customerString);

            String customerFinal =  mockEnd.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody(String.class);
            System.out.println("Customer String:"+customerFinal);


            assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
        }

    }
```

**Exception:Updated**

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.tgt.frs.collections.trm.ceds.routes.FileTest7$1.lambda$0(FileTest7.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)

Comment: The correct solution is to [order your routes' startup order](http://camel.apache.org/configuring-route-startup-ordering-and-autostartup.html), but this test begs the question of what is actually being tested here.  You're mocking out your routes, effectively, and you're only really testing the processors.  It may be better to test the processors in isolation instead of embedded in a route like that, if nothing else, to make for a simpler setup of your tests.

Answer (score 1):

The `CamelContext` is not automatically started by the test framework because you are using `AdviceWith`, to allow you to add advice to routes before they start.  Add a call to `startCamelContext()` at the end of `doPostSetup` after you've added the advice.

Also, `append` doesn't appear to be a valid property of the `file` component so you'll need to remove `append=true`.

Comment: You file uses colon as a separator but you split on comma.  Come on man, read the stack trace!  Debug your code!